# Selenium driven web browser shows a different date format than normally

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, datetime-format, python-behave

When Selenium is not controlling the web browsers I see a `date-time` of the format:
`%a %d %b %Y, %I:%M %p` as expected.
e.g. `Wed 21 Nov 2018, 10:58 am`

When Selenium is controlling the web browsers I see a `date-time` such as:
e.g. `Nov. 21, 2018, 10:58 a.m.`

Why is this Happening? What can I do to fix this?

FURTHER INFORMATION:

When I manually test this in Chrome and Firefox I always get the correct date format. 
When I run my automated Selenium with Behave and Python test case to verify the text in the field which contains the date, I get a different format. The screenshots captured on test failure also show this incorrect date format. 
I have used break point to pause the test and have a look myself. I can clearly see the incorrect date format.

The date-time itself is the correct date-time, just in incorrect format when selenium is controlling the web browser.

Comment: could there be a date configuration needed to be initialised in selenium?

Comment: Update the question with your _code trials_ and relevant _HTML_.

Comment: Are you running both of these tests on the same machine? I seriously doubt Selenium control has anything to do with it. More likely is when you run this manually, you are logging into a profile that has certain settings, etc. that is controlling this and when you run this using Selenium you have no profile.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually test this in Chrome and Firefox"? Do you just go to the website and see that the date-time format is different? If so, it's possible that there's JavaScript updating the page and reformatting the date-time format.